# Recordset Paging works in IIS6 but not in IIIS7

Tags: asp-classic, paging

I've got a recordset/paging set up - works fine in IIS6 but when I run the site on an IIS7 server I get the following error:

```
    Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server  error '80004005'

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

/orders.asp, line 197
```

the code looks like this:

```
  Set objPagingConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

objPagingConn.Open CONN_STRING

Set objPagingRS    = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   objPagingRS.PageSize  = iPageSize
   objPagingRS.CacheSize = iPageSize
   objPagingRS.Open strSQL, objPagingConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

iPageCount   = objPagingRS.PageCount
  iRecordCount  = objPagingRS.RecordCount

Line 197 is the objPagingConn,Open ... line.
I've got about 10 sites like this to migrate - is there a simple fix in IIS7???

Help is greatly appreciated!
Many thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

After many, many experiments I found a connection string that worked:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=123.123.123.123,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sqladmin;Password=password;
```

I hope this helps someone else who comes across the same problem - it's been bugging me for ***so*** long!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you lost permissions to your sql server when you changed over.  What is your connection string?  Are you trying to use a trusted connection?  If so, perhaps IIS7 is running under a different account.

Comment: My current connection string is (like):
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=password;

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888228):

> You may receive this error message
> when the following conditions are
> true:
>
> - SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2000 is installed on a cluster.
> - You are connecting to a SQL Server named instance by using TCP/IP
>   sockets.
> - IPSec policy is enabled on the client domain.
> - IPSec policy is not enabled on the server domain.

They reccomend updating your connection string with the port # or named pipe name:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated
> Security=SSPI;Persist Security
> Info=False;User ID=clientID;Data
> Source=tcp:TcpIpAddress,port

Comment: Cheers - have you got a real world example for a server/password? Or should I look on connectionstrings.com?